# How do I get this handleSubmit on a Formik form to perform a Post request

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx, formik

My handleSubmit function on a Formik form is not properly sending a Post request to my backend API. I believe I have the code 97% of the way there, but don't quite understand the nuances of what is missing.

The form has an email field, and I need the Submit to pass that email string to a POST request. The code below has 4 files at play:  `Enter-Email.js`, `SessionStore.js`, `UserService.js` and `request.js`.

I believe most of the problem is in my `handleSubmit` function in `Enter-Email.js` and my `@action sendResetCode` in `SessionStore.js`.

Thanks for any assistance.

Enter-Email.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react/native";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";

@observer
class EnterEmail extends Component {

    handleSubmit = async ({       <----- function I think has the problem
      email,
      values,
    }) => {
      const {
        navigation: { navigate },
        sessionStore: { sendResetCode }
      } = this.props;

      let response = await sendResetCode({     <------ the function to make the POST request!
        email: email
      });

      if (response) {
        return navigate("VerificationCode", { values });
      } else {
        return Alert(
          { message: "Error sending the reset link" },
          "There was an error sending the reset link. Please try again."
        );
      }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>

                    <Text>Enter your e-mail to receive a link to reset your password</Text>

                    <Formik
                      initialValues={{ email: ''}}
                      onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                      validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
                        email: yup
                        .string()
                        .email()
                        .required(),
                      })}
                    >
                    {({ values, handleChange, setFieldTouched, handleSubmit }) => (
                    <Fragment>

                    <View>
                      <View>
                          <TextInputGroup
                            id="email"
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                            label="Email"
                            onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("email")}
                            value={values.email}
                            onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
                          />
                      </View>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                      <LargeButton
                        text="Send Reset Link"
                        onPress={handleSubmit}
                      />
                    </View>

                    </Fragment>
                  )}
                  </Formik>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

export default EnterEmail;
```

SessionStore.js:

```
@action sendResetCode = async (emailField: Object): Promise<void> => {

     let res = await userService.sendResetCode(emailField);

     // if it fails, return res.success to trigger error on enter-email.js
     if (!res.success) {
         return res.success;
     }
};
```

UserService.js:

```
// to send code to email that was entered:
userService.sendResetCode = async (
    body: Object
): Promise<ApiResponse<Nurse>> => {
    const response: Response = await request.post(        
        `/v1/password_resets`,   <---- backend endpoint which works
        body
    );
    return handleResponse(response);
};
```

request.js:

```
post(url, body, useBody) {
        return fetch(this._buildUrl(url), {
            method: "POST",
            headers: getCommonHeaders(useBody),
            body: useBody ? body : JSON.stringify(body)
        });
},
```

In case it matters, here is the versions in Package.json:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
"native-base": "^2.12.1",
"react": "16.8.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
"formik": "^1.5.8",
"mobx": "5.9.4",
"mobx-react": "5.4.4",
```

Comment: What exactly is not proper about how POST request is sent in your case?